# Adjacency matrix DFS traversal to find number of paths from x to y in DiGraph (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

[image: digraph]
[image: adj matrix]

```
private Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

public int dfs(int maxDepth){ //path A-C with 'x' stops maximum
    int src = 0;
    int dest = 2;
    int i;
    int countDepth = 0;
    int countPaths = 0;
    int element;

    stack.add(src);

    while(!stack.isEmpty() && countDepth <= maxDepth)
    {
        element = stack.pop();
        i = 0;

        while(i < gSize) // i < 5
        {
            if(arr[element][i] > 0)
            {
                stack.add(i);

                if(i == dest)
                    countPaths++;
            }       

            i++;
        }
        countDepth++;
    }
    return countPaths;
}
```

The idea of this code is to find how many paths there are from point A to point B (arbitrary point A and B) with a maximum of 'x' amount of stops. So from C to C with a maximum of 3 stops, there are two possibilities:

C -> D -> C (2 stops)

C -> D - > E -> C (3 stops)

From A to C with a maximum of 3 stops there are 3 possibilities:

A -> B -> C (2 stops)

A -> D -> C (2 stops)

A -> E -> B -> C (3 stops)

However, it just finds one and the program stops. It is because of my countDepth variable. It stops when  `depth > maxDepth`. In other words, it is not traversing my graph like I want it to, it goes down one branch then program stops. How do I keep track of the depth that it is currently at properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing your depth every time you pop something off the stack, and notice you are never decreasing it. So you for loop will only execute `gSize` times.

During a depth first search though, once you reach the end of a path (max length or dead end), you need to go back up the tree, and your depth needs to decrease.

The way I would suggest approaching this is to store both the node and the depth in the stack.

So first you push `(src, 0)` onto the stack.

Then you pop say `(node, i)` off the stack, if `i < gSize` then push `(child, i + 1)` onto the stack for each `child` of `node`. And if `node == dest`, add one to your count.

Answer (score 1):

And actually this can be solved a lot simpler and more efficient this way:

```
int count = -1;
Map<Integer , Integer> nodes = new HashMap<>();
nodes.put(src , 1);

//count the depth at which the algorithm currently is
for(int i = 0 ; i < maxDepth ; i++){
    Map<Integer , Integer> next_nodes = new HashMap<>();

    nodes.stream.forEach(e -> {
        if(e.getKey() == dest)
            count += e.getValue();

        for(int j = 0 ; j < arr[e.getKey()].length ; j++)
            if(arr[e.getKey()][j] > 0)
                if(next_nodes.containsKey(j))
                    next_nodes.put(j , next_nodes.get(j) + e.getValue());
                else
                    next_nodes.put(j , e.getValue());
        });

    nodes = next_nodes;
}
```

The basic idea behind this is to count the number of times we can end up at each node after `n` steps. This reduces the number of steps required per depth to a maximum of `numberOfNodes`, which is quite a lot better than the growth of number of steps in your code (~exponential).